# functions/delegates not matching overloaded template

Tags: templates, d

It looks like D has problems picking the right overloaded template when passing functions and delegates to them.
Take this example:

```
import std.stdio;

void test()(string a){
    writeln(a);
}

void test(Ret, Args...)(Ret function(Args) fn){
    writeln(fn(1, 2));
}

void test(T)(T a){
    assert(0);
}

void main(){
    test("something");
    test((int a, double b){
        return "works";
    });
}
```

Theoretically, this should print `something\nworks`. But this is the output:

```
something
core.exception.AssertError@test.d(15): Assertion failure
...
```

It works when removing `void test(T)(T a)`.

1. Why is `(T a)` the selected match?
2. Is there a way to force the right selection without passing the parameters explicitly, and without calling `(Ret function(Args))` from within `(T a)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [template specialization docs](http://dlang.org/spec/template.html#variadic_template_specialization):

> If both a template with a sequence parameter and a template without a sequence parameter exactly match a template instantiation, the template without a TemplateSequenceParameter is selected.

You can work around it by adding a constraint with [`isSomeFunction`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_traits.html#isSomeFunction):

```
void test(T)(T a) if (!isSomeFunction!T) {
    assert(0);
}
```